# Which 2D drawing/graphics libraries are used in Browser Engines?

Tags: browser, graphics, julia

I am making a browser engine in Julia. I wanted to ask, what kind of 2D drawing/graphics are used to render the html/css in such projects?

Answer (score -1):

i think Vectr, but im not sure. If ur gonna use Vectr then i recommend u make an account or ur design will be temporary.